# python - get key from matching list items with dict value, in list order

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, key

I have this code:

```
d = {'h' : 11111111, 't' : 1010101, 'e' : 10101111, 'n' : 1}

my_list = [1010101, 11111111, 10101111, 1]

get_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if v in my_list]

print(get_keys)
```

The output I get is:

```
['h', 't', 'e', 'n']
```

However I would like it in the order of my_list so:

```
['t', 'h', 'e', 'n']
```

How can I do this? thank you!

Comment: python dictionaries are not ordered. you may want to use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Are the values all unique? Otherwise some of the keys may be ambiguous.

Comment: all are unique yes

Comment: I have sorted it now though, cheers anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'h' : 11111111, 't' : 1010101, 'e' : 10101111, 'n' : 1}

my_list = [1010101, 11111111, 10101111, 1]

new_list = []

for i in my_list:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value == i:
            new_list.append(key)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: For each item in `my_list` you are looping over every item in the dict `d`. Stated another way, this has O(n^2) complexity. Please don't use this....

Answer (score 2):

Given (where all values are also unique):

```
>>> d = {'h' : 11111111, 't' : 1010101, 'e' : 10101111, 'n' : 1}
>>> my_list = [1010101, 11111111, 10101111, 1]
```

You can invert the dict:

```
>>> d_inverted={v:k for k,v in d.items()}
```

Then index as you expect:

```
>>> [d_inverted[e] for e in my_list]
['t', 'h', 'e', 'n']
```

That works for any recent version of Python.

---

Note, the method you posted has `O(n^2)` complexity. That means that the time to execute your code will increase as the square of the number of elements. **Double the elements, you quadruple the execution time.** Bad result.

Visually, looks like this:

[image]

In comparison, the method I posted is `O(n)`, or proportional to the number of elements alone. **Double the data is double the execution time.** Better result. (But not as good as `O(1)` which is the same execution time no matter the size of the data.)

If you want to time them to compare:

```
def bad(d,l):
    new_list = []

    for i in l:
        for key, value in d.items():
            if value == i:
                new_list.append(key)
    return new_list 

def better(d,l):
    d_inverted={v:k for k,v in d.items()}
    return [d_inverted[e] for e in my_list]

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit  
    import random 

    for tgt in (5,10,20,40,80,160,320,640,1280):
        d={chr(i):i for i in range(100,100+tgt)}
        my_list=list(d.values())
        random.shuffle(my_list)
        print("Case of {} elements:".format(len(my_list)))
        for f in (bad, better):
            print("\t{:10s}{:.4f} secs".format(f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f(d,my_list)", setup="from __main__ import f, d, my_list", number=100)))
```

Prints:

```
Case of 5 elements:
    bad       0.0003 secs
    better    0.0001 secs
Case of 10 elements:
    bad       0.0006 secs
    better    0.0002 secs
Case of 20 elements:
    bad       0.0022 secs
    better    0.0003 secs
Case of 40 elements:
    bad       0.0071 secs
    better    0.0004 secs
Case of 80 elements:
    bad       0.0240 secs
    better    0.0008 secs
Case of 160 elements:
    bad       0.0912 secs
    better    0.0018 secs
Case of 320 elements:
    bad       0.3571 secs
    better    0.0032 secs
Case of 640 elements:
    bad       1.3704 secs
    better    0.0053 secs
Case of 1280 elements:
    bad       5.4443 secs
    better    0.0107 secs
```

You can see that the nested loop method starts at `3x` slower and increase to `500x` slower as the size of the data increases. The increase in time tracks closely what the Big O predicts. You can imagine what would happen with millions of elements.